# Android: Firebase push notification different icon while app is on foreground and another while app is on background

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, notifications, android-notifications

How can I show same icon while app is on background or foreground? Below I have attached my screenshot

[image: screenshot of app's notification]

I have used this app icon for my notification

[image: notification icon]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Yes. This does happen. It can be fixed by setting color to the icon ,when the notification is generated from inside the app.

```
 NotificationCompat.Builder(
 this,
 CHANNEL_ID
 )
.setSmallIcon(//your vector)
.setColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, //color of the icon(mostly this may be 
the primary/secondary color that has been set ,according to the theme, in this 
case some hex of red)))
```

To keep it consistent, even for the notification generated in the background, a line can be written in the manifest:

```
<meta-data
android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
android:resource="@drawable/(your vector)” />
<meta-data
android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
android:resource="@color/(color of the icon)” />
```